# Error al validar los campos de un registro (no funciona correctamente el bordeado de error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, algoritmos

Me gustaría saber la manera de hacer, para poder cargar todo el documento Jquery de 1, ya que lo que hace es de arriba a bajo, y cuando por ejemplo , hago la validación de unos campos, al hacer submit,no me muestra todos los campos erróneos (agrega clase "invalid" a los inputs no validados"), sino que lo que hace es, mostrarme los inputs mal, pero solamente 1, entonces al hacer submit, muestra 1 error, al corregirlo, muestra el proximo, y así sucesivamente..

Uso este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<style>
    h1{
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    button{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    div.alerta{
        display: block;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        background: #f8d7da;
        color: #721c24;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #f5c6cb;
        max-width: 350px;

    }
    .form-c{
            position: relative;
            }
            .form-c.valid:not(.invalid) input{
                border: 1px solid green;
            }
            .form-c.valid:not(.invalid):after{
                content: "\2714";
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                bottom: 7px;
            }
            .form-c.invalid input{
                border: 1px solid red;
                position: relative;
            }
            .form-c.invalid:after{
                content: "\26D2";
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                bottom: 7px;
                color: red
            }
</style>

<h1 class="text-center">Bienvenido a Ponte en forma fácil</h1>
<div class="alerta-before justify-content-center">

</div>

<form action="/crear-1" method="POST" class="formulario-registro">

<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
        <div class="form-c">
            <label for="nombre">Introduce tu nombre</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Sergio.." class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
        <div class="form-c">
            <label for="email">Introduce tu email</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email.." class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3 form-c">
        <label for="contraseña">Introduce una contraseña segura:</label>
        <input id="contraseña" type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="No vale tu fecha nacimiento." class="form-control" required>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3 form-c">
        <label for="contraseña-2">Vuelve a introducir la contraseña</label>
        <input id="contraseña-2"  type="password" name="contraseña-2" placeholder="vuelve a introducir la contraseña" class="form-control" required>        
    </div>
</div>

<center>
<button onclick="return validar1()" id="avanzar-2" class="btn btn-info">Registro</button>
</center>

</form>



<script>
function validar1()
{

    var dataName = $("input#nombre").val();

    var expresionName = /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;

    /*Validación campo "nombre"*/
    if (dataName=="" || dataName==null)
    {
        /*$("input#nombre").closest('.form-c').addClass("invalid");*/
        cambiarColor("nombre");
        mostrAlerta("Introduce un nombre");
        return false;   
    }
    else if(!expresionName.test(dataName)){
        cambiarColor("nombre");
        mostrAlerta("No se permiten carácteres especiales o números");
        return false;
    }
    else if(dataName.length<3)
    {
        cambiarColor("nombre");
        mostrAlerta("El nombre debe tener al menos 3 carácteres");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $("input#nombre").closest('.form-c').removeClass("invalid");    
        $("input#nombre").closest('.form-c').addClass("valid"); 
    }


        /*VALIDACIÓN DEL CAMPO "EMAIL"*/

    /*var expresionMail = /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;      falta cambiar la expresión*/
    /*else if(!expresionName.test(dataName)){
        $("input#nombre").closest('.form-c').addClass("invalid");
        mostrAlerta("No se permiten carácteres especiales o números");
    }*/

    var dataMail = $("input#email").val();

    if (dataMail=="" || dataMail==null)
    {
        cambiarColor("email");4
        mostrAlerta("Introduce un correo electrónico");
        return false;   
    }   
    /*else if(dataMail.length<3)
    {
        $("input#nombre").closest('.form-c').addClass("invalid");
        mostrAlerta("El nombre debe tener al menos 3 carácteres");
        return false;
    }*/
    else{
        $("input#email").closest('.form-c').removeClass("invalid"); 
        $("input#email").closest('.form-c').addClass("valid");  
    }

}


function cambiarColor(dato){
    $('#' + dato).closest('.form-c').addClass("invalid");
}
function mostrAlerta(texto){
    $("div.alerta-before").html('<center><div class="alerta"><p style="text-align:center;">'+texto+'</p></div></center>');
}


</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity=>sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Es un validador de formularios, nose si el problema es que lo he montado mal , o que hay alguna manera de cargar todo el script de una vez, ya que si lo hago así, al hacer submit, no me salen todos los errores( agregar la clase"invalid", o hace 1 por 1....*

**ACTUALIZACIÓN (INCRUSTO CODEPEN CON EL CÓDIGO COMPLETO DEL REGISTRO)**

https://codepen.io/Juliian68/pen/rNBExZQ?editors=1010

Comment: porque no mejor validas todos de un solo con for ? te gastas menos codigo validas todos

Comment: No se hacerlo @steven , llevo ya dias con la maldita validación del formulario, la cosa está en que yo tengo un formulario con muchos inputs y es por pasos, entonces hay que darle juego ya que yo uso un boton que no es submit , solo es para pasar a la proxima etapa ( son 3 etapas) y va transitando con fadeIn y FadeOut.. ya he realizado la pregunta varias veces y la gente no contribuye con algo de código o alguna web de referencia para mi caso.. ya que es un poco especial al ser por pasos...

Comment: Puedes pasar el codigo completo en code open y lo que quieres y yo te lo arreglo que dices

Comment: https://codepen.io/Juliian68/pen/rNBExZQ?editors=1010

Comment: Mira al final de este enlace (https://oscargascon.es/validacion-simple-de-formularios-con-jquery/)

Comment: Estas utilizando la letra **ñ** en tus Id no es recomendable cambia la palabra **contraseña** que tienes por **Id** por **contrasena.**